# Javascript to increase month in Unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

I'd like to select a date from 1 to 28 and increase only month
My input is in unix format
for ex,

if date is 1-jan-17, increase only month to 1-Feb-17

28-dec-17 to 28-Jan-18

i want output in UNIX timestamps

i tried with `new Date().getTime()` but i dont know how to increase

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far?

Comment: i have no idea how to do it, for unix time i am adding by seconds like timestamp +86400 to add one day

Comment: `var d1= new Date();d1.setMonth(d1.getMonth() + 1);`

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/software/definitive-guide-to-datetime-manipulation may be useful for reference about changing datetimes, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date is a reference for the different methods that the Date object has.

Comment: my input is in unix format

Answer (score 1):

From your date in UNIX format you can create a variable `const date = new Date(1508836996)`.

You can increase the month `date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);`.

Check the documentation for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
const date = new Date(1508836996)
console.log('date:', date)

const newDate = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1))
console.log('newDate:', newDate)

const newDateTime = newDate.getTime()
console.log('newDateTime:', newDateTime)
```

Comment: my input is in unix format for ex, 1508836996 and i want to increase only month. For JAN and FEB also it should increase only month

Comment: let date = new Date(1508836996000);
 console.log(date);

 date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
 date = Date.parse(date) / 1000;
 console.log(date);